# Remove minimum number of vertices to make all the vertices isolated

Tags: graph

I have a undirected connected graph and I want to isolate all of its vertices by removing not edges but vertices, I want to keep the number of vertex that I remove to the minimum. I know to achieve this I must remove the vertices with the highest degree every time until the graph becomes disconnected. But I need to write a Java program for it and I do not know how to keep track of the vertex with highest degree and which data structure to use. I am given the following inputs.

`{V, E}`: Number of vertices and Edges respectively.
`{A - B}`: Vertex pair specifying an edge

Sample input:

```
4 2
1-2
3-4
```

Sample Output: `2` (that is the minimum number of vertices that need to be removed to make the vertices isolated)

constraints:

```
1 <= V <= 10^5
1 <= E <= 3 * 10^5
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you got a specific run time or space you need to work with?

Comment: I have a different(maybe harder) question that seems a bit related to the kind of problem mentioned here. If you guys can help with this, please do. The link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083012/graph-decomposition-by-deleting-neighborhoods

Answer (score 4):

I second the idea that greedy algorithm is not always optimal here, even though the task is to isolate the vertices, not to disconnect the graph.

The problem here is the [Vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) problem, and it is NP-hard.

For a quick counter-example consider this graph taken from [here](http://sarielhp.org/teach/2004/b/webpage/lec/11_approx_notes.pdf):

[image: Greedy algorithm does not work]

A greedy algorithm would start at the root, but that would take 4 vertices instead of optimal 3.

Answer (score -1):

I would start of with the following DS:

```
class Node
{
    int ID;
    int NumberOfNeighbors;
    List<int> NeighborIDs;
}
```

You then go on to keep all the `Node`s in a maximum heap (where the key is `NumberOfNeighbors`).

Your algorithm should go something like:

```
int numberOfDeletedNodes = 0;

While (!heap.Empty)
{
    node = heap.PopTop();
    foreach (int ID in node.NeighborIDs)
    {
        tempNode = heap.Extract(ID);
        tempNode.NumberOfNeighbors--;
        tempNode.NeighborIDs.Remove(node.ID);
        if (tempNode.NumberOfNeighbors != 0)
            heap.Insert(tempNode);
    }

    numberOfDeletedNodes++;   
}
```

I probably missed some end cases or something, but the general idea is to remove the node with the most neighbors, take care of all the neighbors`*`, and keep going until the heap is empty.

```
* Important: if the neighbors has no more neighbors of its own, it doesn't go back in.
```

Comment: As you said, you missed some cases. I don't really have an easy small counterexample, but one I stumbled upon is ```[(21, 23), (19, 23), (19, 20), (17, 23), (17, 20), (17, 18), (11, 13), (11, 18), (11, 16), (13, 18), (13, 16), (4, 18), (4, 16), (3, 18), (3, 16), (2, 16)]``` where a number represents a collection of that many (unconnected) vertices and an edge of form ```(n, m)``` means that each of the ```n``` vertices is connected to all of the ```m``` vertices. In the first step, your algorithm would remove the group of 17 vertices, although that isn't removed in the optimal solution.

Comment: For the graph {0=[1, 2], 1=[0, 2, 3], 2=[0, 1, 3], 3=[1, 2, 4, 5], 4=[3, 5, 6], 5=[3, 4, 6], 6=[4, 5]}, this algorithm will give 5 as an answer but the minimum is 4. See the @kitsune's answer to understand why.