# Remove minimum number of nodes to make graph disconnected

Tags: graph, vertices

Find the minimum number of nodes that needs to be removed to make graph disconnected( there exists no path from any node to all other nodes). Number of nodes can be 10<sup>5</sup>

Comment: This is a np hard problem known as vertex cover. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419189/remove-minimum-number-of-vertices-to-make-all-the-vertices-isolated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to find a node that is **not** needed to make the graph connected, you need to find a cycle. Once you find a cycle, then you know all those edges in those cycle are not needed. All the remaining edges in the graph are needed to hold the graph together, so you do a simple traversal of the graph and count the number of vertices connected to find the minimum number of nodes that needs to be removed to make graph disconnected. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, just the most efficient in my head. If V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges, the time complexity will be somewhere around O(V + E) + O(V), since the initial cycle finding is O(V + E) and the counting of the nodes is O(V). Since E >= V, the time complexity can be rounded to O(E), but with huge constant factors.

Comment: There can be multiple cycles too. So, how can we find all nodes which belong to any cycle? Pseudocode would be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Consider the graph undirected.

```
totalDegree = sum of degree of all nodes.
while(totalDegree > 0) {
    Remove the node with highest degree and it's edges.
    Update degree count of each node.
    totalDegree = sum of degree of all remaining nodes.
}
remaining nodes are all disconnected
```

Trying to think of a case where it will not give the min number of nodes.

Comment: time complexity seems like - O(EV)
After removing each edge have to update each node's degree and find the max deg node.